# Selenium 2 phpunit move jquery ui slider

Tags: selenium, phpunit

How to move jQuery UI slider with PHPunit selenium 2? I was not able to do it by using dragandrop function.

Comment: After bit research I have managed this by using execute function.

$this->execute(array(
            'script' => "$('#Slider_id').slider('option', 'value', 505);",
            'args' => array()));