# Selenium 2 phpunit get value from injected javascript code

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am using Selenium2TestCaseTest, which can be found [here](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php) 
and I am trying to get the value of a jquery slider, after searching here I have  found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111864/selenium-2-phpunit-move-jquery-ui-slider) solution

```
$this->execute(
              array(
                     'script' => "$('#Slider_id').slider('option', 'value', 505);",
                     'args'   => array()
                   )
              );
```

but it only allows me to change the value of the slider, then I tried to get it's value with these commands:

```
 $this->execute(
                array( 
                       'script' => "$('#Slider_id').slider('option', 'value');",
                       'args'   => array()
                     )
               );
```

and this:

```
 $this->execute(
                 array( 
                        'script' => "$('#Slider_id').slider('value');",
                        'args'   => array()
                      )
                );
```

and it does not return anything (NULL), can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I managed to get a workaround by getting the slider text value via this statement:  
$this->byCssSelector('#messages-slider-value span.value')->text();
however, that's not what I wanted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the value returned by a code you injected to the browser using selenium you need to add `return` before the code you run.
This is relevant to EVERY javascript code you run using selenium, and not specifically to jQuery ui slider.

```
$val = $this->execute([
    'script' => "return $('#Slider_id').slider('option', 'value');"
    'args' => []
]);
```

Much simpler examples:

```
$val1 = $this->execute([
    'script' => "return 1;"
    'args' => []
]);

$val2 = $this->execute([
    'script' => "return Math.max(10, 15);"
    'args' => []
]);

$val3 = $this->execute([
    'script' => "return function(){return 2}();"
    'args' => []
]);
```

Comment: Life saviour. Thank you very much